# Creating backup of postgresql database can't find file

Tags: postgresql

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and I am using Postgresql database. I ran the command

```
pg_dump dbname > db.bak
```

but when I do this, it outputs nothing. I tried to supply a path to the backup and the file does not show up.

My exact commands ran are:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
pg_dump dbname > db.bak
pg_dump dbname > /db.bak
```

Comment: I am also running this from a venv if that makes any difference.

Comment: Oh, can you run the command from the command prompt, and not from within psql?

Comment: From within psql you can type `\! pwd` to see what the current directory is.

Comment: When running outside of psql I get "connection to database "mydb" failed; FATAL: role "john" does not exist.

Comment: the directory is /var/lib/postgresql. I have searched in and I don't see any backups

Comment: Perhaps `pg_dump -U postgres -Fc dbname > db.bak` would work?

Comment: Same error. But if I do pg_dump mydb -U myuser -h localhost -fc it will prompt me for a password. Then when I enter it my screen gets covered with the word "putty" repeatedly along with some gibberish.

Answer (score 2):

`pg_dump -U myuser -h localhost mydb > db.sql`

This worked for me.

Comment: where is the back located ?